# Create library that supports native and suppport fragments/activities

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-support-library

Is there a way to this?

I want to create a fragment, that either extends the support fragment or the default fragment... I think this is not possible, so I ask the question in another way: what's the most beautiful workaround you know/use?

Comment: why would you wanna do that ? there is no need for such thing all you need for fragment and activity exists in support library

Comment: for making public libraries more useable... or, for myself, to write libraries that I can use with old projects which use the support fragments and to use in new projects that only use the new fragments anymore...

Comment: i don't think there is any way to do that. and note that when you use support fragment in all version your app runs with the support fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this is not possible

Correct.

> what's the most beautiful workaround you know/use?

Put the business logic in a separate class (I will call it `FragmentHelper`). Create one fragment class that extends the native `Fragment` implementation, and have it delegate work to the `FragmentHelper`. Create another fragment class that extends the support package's `Fragment` implementation, and have it delegate work to the `FragmentHelper`.

Comment: @prom85: There is nothing stopping you from duplicating the `FragmentHelper` code in each of the two fragment implementations. And, if the helper code is pretty short, that might actually be better in some ways than having all of the glue code between the fragments and the helper.

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing... Just maintaining is a bit complicated then... But, normally I won't do much update work on old projects anymore...